# C# and XML NextSiblling

Tags: c#, xml

I need to find a node by attribute in the XML file and select child and sibling nodes of that note. I tried with below code but it is not working, I get anexception every time:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        OpenFileDialog theDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        theDialog.Title = "Open the XML file";
        theDialog.Filter = "INA Files|*.ina";
        theDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

        if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK);
        {
            string filename = theDialog.FileName;

            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(theDialog.FileName);

            XmlNodeList m_nodeSegmentList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//PROMPT[@Label='OS_F014_SECTION5B']");

            foreach (XmlNode m_nodeSegment in m_nodeSegmentList)
            {
                var nSegment = m_nodeSegment.NextSibling.InnerXml;
            }
          }
}
```

following code works perfect in VB, but i can not get the C# to select nodes below the node with a certain attribute:

```
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
        Dim m_nodeSegmentList As XmlNodeList
        'Dim m_nodeSegment As XmlNode
        'Create the XML Document
        m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
        'Load the Xml file
        m_xmld.Load("C:\OS_US_14_0084_F14_O.ina")
        'Get the list of name nodes 
        m_nodeSegmentList = m_xmld.SelectNodes("//PROMPT[@Label='OS_F014_SECTION5B1']")

        'MsgBox(m_nodelist.Count)

        'Loop through the nodes
        For Each m_nodeSegment As XmlNode In m_nodeSegmentList
            Dim nSegment As Integer = m_nodeSegment.NextSibling.InnerXml
            MsgBox(nSegment)

            Dim m_nodeLeg As XmlNode
            m_nodeLeg = m_nodeSegment.ParentNode.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling
            'MsgBox(m_nodeLeg.OuterXml)

            Dim m_nodeEntriesList As XmlNodeList = m_nodeLeg.SelectNodes("//ENTRY")
            For Each m_nodeEntry As XmlNode In m_nodeEntriesList
                MsgBox(m_nodeEntry.OuterXml)
            Next




        Next
    Catch errorVariable As Exception
        'Error trapping
        Console.Write(errorVariable.ToString())
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the exception _exactly_? On which line? You sure you have `;` at the end your `if` line? You code won't _even_ compile in your case. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: I have ; at the end of if line. The probelm I have is that the m_nodeSegment a note selected, but when I want to see the nextsibling note of it it does not work. :

Comment: What does the XML look like?  That would help someone reproduce the issue.

Comment: <PROMPT Label="OS_F014_SECTION5B">ITINERARY</PROMPT>
    </GROUP>
    <ETC>
     <SECTION>
      <GROUP>
       <NUMBER>(1)</NUMBER>

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31071570/edit) and add the xml there. Don't post the xml in comments, it's difficult to read.

Comment: In the tiny snippet you've added as a comment, `Prompt` doesn't have a sibling after it, so I'm not surprised it fails.  Your VB snippet selects an element with a *different* label - maybe this one has a sibling? *Add the full XML to the question* and explain what your code is *supposed* to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would use in this case XML Linq.  I fixed the XML so it is valid.

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string XML = "<Root><PROMPT Label=\"OS_F014_SECTION5B\">ITINERARY</PROMPT> <GROUP> <ETC> <SECTION> </SECTION> </ETC>  </GROUP> <NUMBER>(1)</NUMBER></Root>";
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(XML);

            var results = doc.Descendants("PROMPT").Where(x => x.Attribute("Label").Value == "OS_F014_SECTION5B"); 

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: following code works perfeclty in VB but I can not get it to work in the C sharp. It always selects just a first node and I can not select all the nodes in the xml file below the node with a certain attribute.

Comment: This doesn't get the next sibling element after prompt so it's not equivalent. There is no sibling, which is why the original code fails.